# Why is my img and search bar not staying in my nav bar?

Tags: css

I have a nav bar and an image and search bar that i want placed inside the nav bar, furthest to the right.

I posted a thread about this the other day and was told to create a container div and nest the img and search bar inside and then float the container right.  I've tried doing this, but I'm still having issues.  The search bar is overlapping the nav bar instead of being inside it and the profile picture is nowhere to be seen.  I have included a more detailed example of my code and I'm hoping someone can find what exactly I'm doing wrong here.

```
<nav>   
    <ul>
        <li class="drop">
            <div class="user-avatar">
                <img src="http://www.b.com/img.ihttp://c3e308.medialib.glogster.com/teebing/media/68/687cc4e9a6c1aeb052c522de735ca61842054334/cookiemonsterface.jpg" alt=""" />
            </div>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="head-search">
    <span>Search</span>
        <form id="searchform">
            <input placeholder="Search">
            <input type="button" class="btn">
        </form>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/hlEjs

Comment: in your `.user-avatar img` class, add `float: right;`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/izGhg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `.user-avatar img` class, add `float: right;`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/izGhg

Comment: Thanks.  This put the search bar in the correct space but I'm still not sure where the image is. It does not appear anywhere.